# Storm vs Kafka and Processors

Tags: apache-storm, apache-kafka

I am finding it unclear reading the storm documentation exactly what apache storm gives me over having small processes that consume from a kafka topic and produce to another topic?  With this architecture I can change the number of each of these worker processes to suit which components are slower etc.  Presumably storm will give me auomatic fault tolerance and ease of re-balancing?  Are there likely to be any performance improvements?

Comment: Well, for instance: Map/Reduce strategies based on kafka output are easy in Storm. You should really start with storm-starter, run the app and reformulate your question. As it is, it seems clueless.

Comment: I started playing and moved on to Trident but it seems to have quite a steep learning curve and be quite complex.  Also, the incompatibility with Clojure 1.6 would be quite an issue for me, I can't use any library that uses `some?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Presumably storm will give me auomatic fault tolerance and ease of re-balancing?

Yep, it's all about fault tolerance and rebalancing:

Storm will keep an eye on most of the components and tracks whether batch was successfully replayed or not. If it's not, it will conveniently replay it. UI and logviewer are quite minor additions. The other good thing is that Storm already have integration with all major databases/queues (HDFS, Kafka, Kestrel, Cassandra, etc), but since you already solid on input type it's likely not that important for you.

> Are there likely to be any performance improvements?

More like the opposite. Off-the-shelf solutions with quite general scope almost always less performant than ad-hoc systems. In particular, on windowed join task we were able to have process ~120k records per second on a cluster of 6 machines, whereas our own POC designed specifically for this task shown > 2.5x throughput. If you're not going to use Storm as a platform for a variety of different pipelines it worth considering rolling your own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Not only storm provides fault tolerance and re-balancing features, it also have some other features that are suitable for real time event processing

1. Message processing guarantee. The core storm has "**at least once**"
   guarantee and Messages are only replayed when there are failures.
   Trident has "**exact once**" guarantee
2. Ease of distributed deployment.
       All you need to do is submit your topology jar to the cluster.
3. Different part of the topology allows different level of
       parallelism.
4. Different types of grouping support. Grouping pattern
       such as fieldsGrouping makes the stream join much eaiser.

Of course, if your event processing use case is very simple straight fowward and none of the above are required in your architecture, starting multiple java processes manually to read messages off Kafka topic should have better performance. But in reality, it is hardly the case.